# javascript Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollspy is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using this start bootstrap one page freelancer theme to make blog website with ruby on rails. I get this weird javascript error saying Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollspy is not a function.

[error showing scrollspy not working from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5sZm.png)

Comment: You are maybe loading jQuery more than once. Check it.

Comment: Otherwise try $ to jQuery.

Comment: I checked and you are right i am loading jQuery more than once when i use <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %> or <%= stylesheet_link_tag
params[:controller] %> i have to update my application.js to make sure i don't use require_tree. Now it doesn't show any error.

Comment: So you tried $ to Jquery Right ?
Is your issue resolved ?

Comment: No i only updated application.js on rails asset pipeline where i removed require_tree. It wasn't jQuery it was rails controller assets